# Is It possible to start a Group FaceTime call with URL schemes (FaceTime Links)?

Tags: ios, swift, facetime

I know I can start a FaceTime call from within my iOS app with URL Schemes like this:

facetime://user@example.com

I was wondering if it is also possible to start a FaceTime call with multiple users. Tried to separate it with a , or ; but it didn't work.

More information on FaceTime links:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/FacetimeLinks/FacetimeLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH2-SW1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I've been in contact with Apple and it turns out there is a URL scheme for group calls:

facetime-group://?remoteMembers=+12345678901;participant2@apple.com;+23456789012&isVideoEnabled=1 (make the last term 0 if you want to start with your camera off… works the same as tapping Audio when starting a Group FaceTime call)

Comment: Trying in iOS 14.7 and it's very buggy. Problem 1) When using facetime-group://?remoteMembers=APPLEID1;APPLEID2&isVideoEnabled=1, the facetime calls if make 2 request. Problem 2) It doesn't open FaceTime, it just makes the top bar green and when I press it, nothing happens.I have to sleep my phone, then come back to see the facetime. Any workaround for this?